# Dynamic method switching in Python C extensions

Tags: python, c, class, methods

I would like to create a Python C extension module with a class that can dynamically alias/change/select its methods based on the `__init__()` method argument values.  I have not been able to find a solution in the 'Extending and Embedding the Python Interpreter' documentation.  To illustrate, here is a working Python example that I would like to create the equivalent Python C extension class of:

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self, var):
        if var == 'x':
            self.func = self.func_x
        else:
            self.func = self.func_y

    def func_x(self):
        print('func_x')

    def func_y(self): 
        print('func_y')

list = [Test('x'), Test('y'), Test('z')]
for i in range(len(list)):
    list[i].func()
```

I would like to write a C code equivalent of the `Test` class but create the `list` object, with Python C extension `Test` elements with aliased `func()` methods, in Python.

As an example implementation, taking the Python documentation example of the `Noddy` class of the `noddy2` module at https://docs.python.org/2/extending/newtypes.html#adding-data-and-methods-to-the-basic-example, how could this example Python C extension code be extended to allow this dynamic method switching in the `Noddy_init()` function?  The `Noddy_name()` function could be duplicated and modified, and then `Noddy_init()` modified to set `self.func` to one or the other based on the `first` argument value.  Would you define `self.func()` as a `PyMemberDef` or a `PyObject`?  Should it be registered in the `PyTypeObject` via *tp_methods* or *tp_members*?  And after defining `self.func()`, how could the desired C function be dynamically aliased to it?

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You can implement method `func` in C by regular `PyMethodDef` and call either `func_a` or `func_b` from `func` depending on flag stored in constructor.

Comment: This is a great workaround for such a problem.  It's probably the simplest to implement as well.  However there is one downside - speed.  In the Python example, the class method aliasing is occurring during class instantiation.  Therefore the logic only occurs once and `func()` can be called many times.  In my problem, `func()` is actually an optimisation target function so that the penalty for the switching logic within `func()` is rather high.  In such cases, having the function switching logic occur during class instantiation would be preferable.

Comment: Well, workaround will be much faster than Python code anyway. If you need extra speed you can recall about [function pointers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_pointer#Example_in_C) and store pointer to `func_a` or `func_b` instead of a flag.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a different workaround or hack to this problem which can solve the speed issue.  However this is not an ideal or true Pythonic solution as it does not alias the class methods upon class instantiation via the `__init__()` method arguments.  It is also not ideal as the `func() = NULL` method definition may cause problems.  This trick is to have a custom `__getattr__()` method which returns the desired method for `func()`.

Below is the C code that implements the `Test` Python class of the original question (it is both Python 2 and 3 compatible).  As the `__getattr__()` method is called when creating the `list` variable in the example, this is only called once per list element.  So when used in this way the switching logic only occurs once for multiple calls of `func()`, solving the speed issue.

```
#include <Python.h>
#include "structmember.h"
#include <stdio.h>

/* Declaration of the Test class and its contents. */
typedef struct {
    PyObject_HEAD
    PyObject *var;    /* The self.var string. */
} Test;


/* Class method func_x. */
static PyObject * func_x(Test *self, PyObject *args) {
    printf("func_x\n");
    Py_INCREF(Py_None);
    return Py_None;
}


/* Class method func_y. */
static PyObject * func_y(Test *self, PyObject *args) {
    printf("func_y\n");
    Py_INCREF(Py_None);
    return Py_None;
}


/* Definition of all functions of the test module. */
static PyMethodDef test_methods[] = {
    {NULL, NULL, 0, NULL}        /* Sentinel. */
};


/* Definition of all methods of the Test class. */
static PyMethodDef Test_methods[] = {
    {"func", NULL, METH_VARARGS, "Target function alias."},
    {"func_x", (PyCFunction)func_x, METH_NOARGS, "Target function X." },
    {"func_y", (PyCFunction)func_y, METH_NOARGS, "Target function Y."},
    {NULL}  /* Sentinel */
};


/* Definition of the class instance objects. */
static PyMemberDef Test_members[] = {
    {"var", T_OBJECT_EX, offsetof(Test, var), 0, "The function choice."},
    {NULL}  /* Sentinel */
};


/* Class destruction. */
static void Test_dealloc(Test *self)
{
    Py_XDECREF(self->var);
    #if PY_MAJOR_VERSION >= 3
        Py_TYPE(self)->tp_free((PyObject*)self);
    #else
        self->ob_type->tp_free((PyObject*)self);
    #endif
}


/* The Test.__getattr__() instance method for obtaining instance attributes. */
static PyObject *
Test_getattro(Test *self, PyObject *object)
{
    PyObject *objname_bytes, *result = NULL;
    char *objname, *var;

    /* The variable name and object name. */
    #if PY_MAJOR_VERSION >= 3
        var = PyBytes_AsString(self->var);
        objname_bytes = PyUnicode_AsEncodedString(object, "utf-8", "strict");
        objname = PyBytes_AsString(objname_bytes);
    #else
        var = PyString_AsString(self->var);
        objname = PyString_AsString(object);
    #endif

    /* Target function aliasing. */
    if (strcmp(objname, "func") == 0) {
        if (strcmp(var, "x") == 0)
            result = PyObject_GetAttrString((PyObject *)self, "func_x");
        else
            result = PyObject_GetAttrString((PyObject *)self, "func_y");
    }

    /* Normal attribute handling (nothing else to return). */
    else
        result = PyObject_GenericGetAttr((PyObject *)self, object);

    return result;
}


/* The Test.__new__() method definition for creating the class. */
static PyObject *
Test_new(PyTypeObject *type, PyObject *args, PyObject *kwds)
{
    Test *self;

    self = (Test *)type->tp_alloc(type, 0);
    if (self != NULL) {
        /* Set up the function choice variable to the empty string. */
        #if PY_MAJOR_VERSION >= 3
            self->var = PyUnicode_FromString("");
        #else
            self->var = PyString_FromString("");
        #endif
    }

    return (PyObject *)self;
}


/* The Test.__init__() method definition for initialising the class. */
static int
Test_init(Test *self, PyObject *args, PyObject *keywords)
{
    PyObject *var=NULL, *tmp;

    /* The keyword list. */
    static char *keyword_list[] = {"var", NULL};

    /* Parse the function arguments. */
    if (! PyArg_ParseTupleAndKeywords(args, keywords, "|S", keyword_list, &var))
        return -1;

    /* Store the arguments in self. */
    if (var) {
        tmp = self->var;
        Py_INCREF(var);
        self->var = var;
        Py_XDECREF(tmp);
    }

    return 0;
}


/* Define the type object to create the class. */
static PyTypeObject Test_type = {
    #if PY_MAJOR_VERSION >= 3
        PyVarObject_HEAD_INIT(NULL, 0)
    #else
        PyObject_HEAD_INIT(NULL)
        0,                                  /*ob_size*/
    #endif
    "test.Test",                            /*tp_name*/
    sizeof(Test),                           /*tp_basicsize*/
    0,                                      /*tp_itemsize*/
    (destructor)Test_dealloc,               /*tp_dealloc*/
    0,                                      /*tp_print*/
    0,                                      /*tp_getattr*/
    0,                                      /*tp_setattr*/
    0,                                      /*tp_compare*/
    0,                                      /*tp_repr*/
    0,                                      /*tp_as_number*/
    0,                                      /*tp_as_sequence*/
    0,                                      /*tp_as_mapping*/
    0,                                      /*tp_hash */
    0,                                      /*tp_call*/
    0,                                      /*tp_str*/
    (getattrofunc)Test_getattro,            /*tp_getattro*/
    0,                                      /*tp_setattro*/
    0,                                      /*tp_as_buffer*/
    Py_TPFLAGS_DEFAULT | Py_TPFLAGS_BASETYPE,    /*tp_flags*/
    "Test class.",                          /* tp_doc */
    0,                                      /* tp_traverse */
    0,                                      /* tp_clear */
    0,                                      /* tp_richcompare */
    0,                                      /* tp_weaklistoffset */
    0,                                      /* tp_iter */
    0,                                      /* tp_iternext */
    Test_methods,                           /* tp_methods */
    Test_members,                           /* tp_members */
    0,                                      /* tp_getset */
    0,                                      /* tp_base */
    0,                                      /* tp_dict */
    0,                                      /* tp_descr_get */
    0,                                      /* tp_descr_set */
    0,                                      /* tp_dictoffset */
    (initproc)Test_init,                    /* tp_init */
    0,                                      /* tp_alloc */
    Test_new,                               /* tp_new */
};


/* Define the Python 3 module. */
#if PY_MAJOR_VERSION >= 3
    static PyModuleDef moduledef = {
        PyModuleDef_HEAD_INIT,
        "test",       /* m_name */
        "C module.",  /* m_doc */
        -1,           /* m_size */
        NULL,         /* m_reload */
        NULL,         /* m_traverse */
        NULL,         /* m_clear */
        NULL,         /* m_free */
    };
#endif


/* Declarations for DLL import/export */
#ifndef PyMODINIT_FUNC
#define PyMODINIT_FUNC void
#endif


/* Initialise as a Python module. */
PyMODINIT_FUNC
#if PY_MAJOR_VERSION >= 3
    PyInit_test(void)
    {
        PyObject* m;

        if (PyType_Ready(&Test_type) < 0)
            return NULL;

        m = PyModule_Create(&moduledef);
        if (m == NULL)
            return NULL;

        Py_INCREF(&Test_type);
        PyModule_AddObject(m, "Test", (PyObject *)&Test_type);

        return m;
    }
#else
    inittest(void)
    {
        PyObject* m;

        if (PyType_Ready(&Test_type) < 0)
            return;

        m = Py_InitModule3("test", test_methods,
                           "Example module that creates an extension type.");
        if (m == NULL)
            return;

        Py_INCREF(&Test_type);
        PyModule_AddObject(m, "Test", (PyObject *)&Test_type);
    }
#endif
```

A different solution I tried was to change the contents of the `Test_methods` list in the `__init__()` method.  But this changes the class methods rather than the instance methods.  Hence in the original Python list example, 'func_y' is printed 3 times, rather than the desired result of 'func_x', 'func_y', and 'func_y', showing that this is not a solution in this case.

**EDIT:**

This code is actually not a solution, as the Python `__getattr__()` method is called for each `func()` function call!

**EDIT 2:**

To obtain a functional *.so module that can be imported in Python, copy the code into the `test.c` file and type:

```
cc $(python-config --cflags --ldflags) -o test.os -c -fPIC test.c
cc -o test.so -shared test.os
```